# How to remove <adinsight> sting from json object from facebook insight API Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, serialization, facebook-business-sdk

I am making api call via python sdk to get facebook insights dat and I am getting the following response from API. I would like to remove  from response json object. can you please guide me how to do this? I have tried to serialize it by .dumps() but it does not serialize.
[
 {
"account_id": "123"
},
 {
"account_id": "123"
},
 {
"account_id": "123"
}
]

Comment: I would like to remove< AdsInsights> from this json object  [<AdsInsights>
 { "account_id": "123" }, <AdsInsights>{ "account_id": "123" }, <AdsInsights>{ "account_id": "123" } ]

Comment: solve by using dict

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just cast the insights list into a Pandas Dataframe like:

```
    insights_list = campaign.get_insights()
    insights_df = pd.Dataframe(insights_list)
```

In this way you can have your metrics in the dataframe columns and it will improve the readability.